# Using max() to find highest in a list, and if they tie, choose only one

Tags: python, random, max

I'm making a voting software and having some problems. Here is a sample:

```
import random

One = "James"
Two = "Tabitha"
Three = "Emory"

running = {One: 0, Two: 0, Three: 0}

#Enter voting code here

winner = max(running)
```

I want to make it so if two candidates tie for the win, it will randomly select one of them as the winner. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: " (Ignore me not defining One - Six)" now you have to refactorate all the rest of your code...

Comment: Why are you assigning to keys that don't exist inside the loop?

Comment: Your logic here doesn't appear to make much sense. Why aren't you adding the vote just with `running[vote] += 1` ?

Comment: @khelwood, that doesn't really matter as of right now. I'm asking how to do something, not for people to criticize me. Its the same either way.

Comment: If no one can make sense of your code, it is harder for anyone to help.

Comment: @H.Tacon, in the real code, One - Six would be strings, so it really doesn't matter for me to define them. It's just a sample code.

Comment: @SanguineL I understand that it is just a sample code, but you need to have in mind that the people that are trying to help you will expect a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have the minimun conditions colaborate with you.

Comment: Instead of posting fake code that doesn't actually make sense and telling us it doesn't matter, you could have saved us all this confusion by posting code that just makes sense.

Comment: Is this any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the max number of votes, and then select the key(s) from the dictionary that have that value:

```
max_votes = max(running.values())
winners = [candidate for candidate, votes in running.items() if votes == max_votes]
winner = random.choice(winners)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just added all the candidates to winners and randomly selected one.

Comment: @SanguineL: Then all the candidates got the same number of votes. That, or what you tried doesn't actually match this answer, or it didn't actually add all the candidates to the list.

Answer (score -1):

```
winners=[]

for key,value in running:
  if value == winner
    winners.append(key)

 <pick random person from winners>
```

Comment: What is `winner`?

Comment: @clabe45: `winner` is assigned to `max(running)` in the code in the question.

Comment: (That's not the right way to compute the winner, but it's there.)

Comment: @clabe45: It's right there, in the last line. [Here, I've marked it in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Zqk.png)

Comment: Oh, I missed that, my bad. You should probably at least include the relevant code to select the random person from `winners`, and properly format it to help other people though.